# How to return an object after removing it from an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I was thinking of doing it like this, but I'm not sure if the reference temp is assigned will still be valid after removal.

```
public Box removeBox(int index)
{
Box temp=getBoxes().get(index);//ArrayList.get
getBoxes().remove(index);
return temp;
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct. But, the Louis Wasserman answer is more clean. As advice, read the APIs to optimize the codes, some functions in Java can be amazing when you know well how they work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's fine, although `return getBoxes().remove(index)` would do the same thing in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a valid way of doing it. Java works with values, not references.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reference will still be valid, as there already exists a reference to it (the `temp` variable you just defined). The JVM's garbage collector will take care of all dereferenced objects when it runs. See this link for more information: [**How Garbage Collection works in Java**](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html), specially *When an Object becomes Eligible for Garbage Collection*.

[`ArrayList#remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) returns the removed element, if any, so you could also just do `return getBoxes().remove(index)`.

Answer (score 0):

`List.remove()` doesn't invalidate the removed object.

Removing any element from any Collection doesn't invalidate it.

Answer (score 0):

you are going great , The reference will be valid

Lets take an example

A---------Object

B---------Object

A and B both are references of Object .

Now, say the reference B is invalidated

A---------Object

B--|-|-|-|--|-|-Object (Invalidated)

the reference A still remains intact.

Thanks
Abhi